# Postgres NOT IN not working

Tags: sql, postgresql, notin

If I use:

```
SELECT *
  FROM "moves"
 INNER
  JOIN "move_conditions"
    ON "move_conditions"."move_id" = "moves"."id"
 INNER
  JOIN "conditions"
    ON "conditions"."id" = "move_conditions"."condition_id"
 WHERE "conditions"."id" IN (29, 3)
```

This returns the correct tables where conditions have an id of 29 or 3.

However, if I try:

```
SELECT *
  FROM "moves"
 INNER
  JOIN "move_conditions"
    ON "move_conditions"."move_id" = "moves"."id"
 INNER
  JOIN "conditions"
    ON "conditions"."id" = "move_conditions"."condition_id"
 WHERE "conditions"."id" NOT IN (29, 3)
```

The result is incorrect. Conditions with id 29 or 3 are in the result. They should not be. How do I fix this?

Comment: Please post sample data (e.g. on http://sqlfiddle.com). `NOT IN` is **definitely** working correcly in PostgreSQL

Comment: This seems OK, could you post your whole query?

Comment: Maybe it is `from tbl1, tbl2 where` style query?

Comment: Maybe the example provided isn't as acurate as it should be but make sure that there is no `NULL` value in checked conditions: 

    NOT IN (NULL, 29, 3)

Comment: Try rewriting to conditions.id <> 29 and conditions.id <> 3.. and see if they are okay. Or also try casting conditions.id::int.

Comment: Are you use you don't have `not in ('29, 3')`?

Comment: The description contradicts the query, which would *never* return rows with "conditions"."id" 29 or 3. Maybe you are confused by a column of the same name from one of the other tables?

Comment: No, the query is proper. The problem is that it is a HABTM relationship between moves and conditions. So, there are some records that are returning true. I need to say that if a move has ANY conditions that fail, then the move should be excluded. I tried using an ANY statement  `WHERE NOT "move_conditions"."condition_id" = ANY(array[29, 3])` but that returns the same result. I am currently subtracting the IN conditions array from the full return - but that requires two queries so it is a bit silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean that you want to disqualify a move if *any* of its conditions is 29 or 3? I'd try a subquery for that.

```
SELECT *
  FROM "moves"
WHERE moves.id
NOT IN 
    (SELECT /* Don't know if PG infers or would be faster
                 with the DISTINCT that is implied by NOT IN */
      moves.id FROM 
      move_conditions 
      INNER JOIN
      conditions
    ON move_conditions.condition_id=conditions.id
    WHERE conditions.id IN (29,3)
    )
```

Or you could try

```
SELECT *
  FROM moves
EXCEPT
SELECT *
  FROM "moves"
INNER
JOIN "move_conditions"
   ON "move_conditions"."move_id" = "moves"."id"
INNER
JOIN "conditions"
ON "conditions"."id" = "move_conditions"."condition_id"
WHERE "conditions"."id" IN (29, 3)
```

although I'd expect that to be much slower.

You can convert the first version to use `NOT EXISTS` instead of `NOT IN`; versions of PG optimize those differently and one may be faster than the other.